# Best way to compare two any type values in swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, anyobject

I have a class which has `property value` of type `Any` I have implemented a `didSet` method for the value like this

```
didSet {
  if oldValue == nil && self.value != nil {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    if let val = self.value as? AnyHashable, let oldVal = oldValue as? AnyHashable {
      if val != oldVal {
        // do something 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My value is `optional` type so I want to verify the `nil` case too.
Is there are better way of doing that I do not want to cast to `Anyhashasble` I want them to be casted to the class they belong.

Comment: I hope there is better way. But since you didn't show enough details, you can't expect that you'll receive any helpful answer. You can share your whole class, but more important... tell why you need to have property of type `Any`. I think there has to be solution without using `Any`

Comment: The value is an generic input for a set of form fields so , the value can be of type dictionary , array, string, int , date etc.

I would have avoided `Any` , and also possibly found a better solution if possible 
Without coming to this platform!

It is a informed swift question

Comment: "array, string, int, date, etc" is not "Any." Can it be a UIViewController? A CBPeripheral? A UIApplication? "Any" means *absolutely anything*. Generic form management is challenging (tying together arbitrary UI elements to arbitrary data storage); I've built them. But you don't need Any for it. This "equality" problem is just the first of numerous problems you're going to face with Any. Get rid of the Any. (To this specific question, this problem is not solvable.)

Comment: BTW, the fact that you've elevated this to Any? makes the rabbit hole much deeper. Any? is itself of type Any. So you can easily get into recursive situations like Optional(nil) (.some(.none)), which is not the same thing as nil (.none). It's very difficult to work with Any. It is a complete nightmare to work with Any?. Everything will seem fine until you find yourself in bizarre corners.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you assume that this property is aways, and if only always, a reference type, then you can try to use `AnyObject` instead of `Any` and use `===` operator to check if pointers are pointing to same object.

Something like this:

```
class Test {

    var object: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            if oldValue === object {
                debugPrint("Old object")
            } else {
                debugPrint("New object")
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass {}

let test = Test()
let s = SomeClass()

test.object = s
test.object = s
test.object = SomeClass()
```

The result will be:

`"New object"` - because previous value was `nil`

`"Old object"` - because we assigned same `s`

`"New object"` - because we assigned completely new object